# Nullpointer Exception on return value from a DAO method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-room, viewmodel, dao

I am using a Roomdatabase and I wish to search get a single object from the database when I give it's name. For that I wrote this Query in the DAO :

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM kuh_table WHERE name = :kuhName ")
    Kuh findKuh(String kuhName);
```

I call it in the repository this way :

```
public Kuh findKuh(String kuhName){
        final Kuh[] kuh = new Kuh[1];
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            volatile boolean running = true;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(running!= true) {
                    return;
                }
                kuh[0] =kuhDAO.findKuh(kuhName);
                running = false;
            }
        }).start();
        return kuh[0];
    }
```

then in my ViewModel this way :

```
public Kuh findKuh(String kuhName){ return repository.findKuh(kuhName);}
```

I then initialize my ViewModel in a fragment and try using the method by giving a String like this:

```
MarkerApiKt.setMarkerTapListener(mapView, (MarkerTapListener) (new MarkerTapListener() {
                public void onMarkerTap(@NotNull View view, int x, int y) {
                    Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(view, "view");
                    if (view instanceof MapMarker) {
                        MarkerCallout callout = new MarkerCallout(context);
                        callout.setTitle(((MapMarker) view).getName());
                        callout.setSubTitle("position: " + ((MapMarker) view).getX() + " , " + ((MapMarker) view).getY());
                        Kuh kuh = kuhViewModel.findKuh(((MapMarker) view).getName());
                        Toast.makeText(context, "this is "+ kuh.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but somehow the istance of my object is always null since I end up with a nullpointer exception.
Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: You are starting a new thread, which should get the object from your DAO. This code runs on another thread, so the program doesn't wait for it to finnish. After calling thread.start(); The program instantly processes the next line, which tries to get the first element of your array. At this point, your thread has not finnished and didn't put the object inside your array. So there is no object in kun[0].

Comment: Try this:  @Query("SELECT * FROM kuh_table WHERE name = :kuhName" AND name IS NOT NULL)

Comment: @Olli how would you wait for the thread to finnish in this case?

Comment: @PrajwalWaingankar sadly that didn´t work, I still get a nullpointerException

Comment: You should be able to do this without using another thread. If the DAO operation cosumes so much time that it will freeze the gui, you should read up on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask This will give you a function to override which will be executed in the background (get result from DAO) and a function to override which will be executed on the gui thread when the background thread has finnished (process your DAO result in gui). Just waiting inside your getKuh function until the DAO operation is finnished, would be the same as doing it without the thread i think.

Comment: @Olli I would have normally used Asynctask in my Repository but since it has been deprecated I had to use just simple threads this way.

Comment: @HédiGuellouz I didn't know that it is deprecated. I found this https://medium.com/swlh/asynctask-is-deprecated-now-what-f30c31362761 article, maybe you can use this way of implementing async tasks. But I don't know if there is an offical way / best practice for these kind of situations without AsyncTask :/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as @Olli said, the problem was that my thread in my Repository didn't finish its execution, which is why it returned a null object.

I just changed my code this way and now it works fine

```
public Kuh findKuh(String kuhName) throws InterruptedException {
        final Kuh[] kuh = new Kuh[1];
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            volatile boolean running = true;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(running!= true) {
                    return;
                }
                kuh[0] =kuhDAO.findKuh(kuhName);
                running = false;
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t1.join();
        return kuh[0];
    }
```